# Ant Design Dynamic field validation

Tags: validation, antd

Im trying to create dynamic field validator - when "isDisable" is true then it is not required + no need to check number type.

```
{getFieldDecorator('number', {
  validateFirst: true,
  rules: [{
    required: !isDisable,
    message: 'Must enter data'
  }, {
    type: 'number',
    message: 'Need to enter number'
  }]
})(
  <InputNumber min={0} step={1} disabled={isDisable} />
)}
```

But this code still checks number type.

I also tried this in render function:

```
const rules = isDisable ? { } : {
  validateFirst: true,
  rules: [{
    required: true,
    message: 'Must enter data'
  }, {
    type: 'number',
    message: 'Need to enter number'
  }]
};

{getFieldDecorator('number', rules)(
  <InputNumber min={0} step={1} disabled={isDisable} />
)}
```

But when entering data the validator only occurs when "validateFieldsAndScroll" function called, and I want it to validate onChange event

So how can I create a rule that doesn't check the type if the field is disabled?

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
const allFields = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const fields = allFields.filter(disabledField);
this.props.form.validateFields(fields, () => {...})
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I also found that if you set the value of the field as undefined the validator wont check it.